# Do I install the Wordpress theme to Softaculous before I purchase the premium Wordpress theme?

Tags: wordpress, themes, softaculous

I'm creating a website using Wordpress. I have set up a subdomain in my web host control panel, so that is ready. I need to know in this process when to purchase the [Premium WordPress Themes](http://www.themesin.com/), and what will happen when I do. Should I install Wordpress into Softaculous, and then purchase the theme? Or should I purchase the theme, then install Wordpress?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can't install that theme - or any theme - until you install Wordpress. See http://codex.wordpress.org/Getting_Started_with_WordPress